# OpenMP - how to get rid of implicit data maps?

Tags: gpu, openmp, data-transfer

Please take look at the following example:

```
#include<cstdio>
#include<omp.h>

int main()
{
    int x[100];
    for(int i=0; i<100; i++)
        x[i] = 1;

#pragma omp target data map(to:x)
    {
    #pragma omp target
        {
        for(int i=0; i<100; i++)
            x[i] = 2;
        
        printf("%d\n",x[0]); //I expect 2
        }

    printf("%d\n",x[0]); //not sure...
    }

    printf("%d\n",x[0]); //I expect 1

    return 0;
}
```

I compile it with `nvc++ -Minfo=mp -mp=gpu -gpu=cc80 test2.cpp` and get:

```
main:
     13, #omp target
         11, Generating map(to:x[:]) 
         13, Generating "nvkernel_main_F1L13_2" GPU kernel
     13, Generating implicit map(tofrom:x[:])
```

This example is of course a bit silly, but lets say, I just don't want this implicit map. How can I prevent this from happening?

When I explicitly add:

```
#pragma omp target map(to:x)
```

then I get:

```
main:
     13, #omp target
         11, Generating map(to:x[:]) 
         13, Generating "nvkernel_main_F1L13_2" GPU kernel
     13, Generating map(to:x[:])
```

In theory, I no longer have a `from` mapping, but the host somehow knows that the value was updated and all the prints return 2. Why is that? Btw. was the data copied `to` twice in this case?